# what is the difference between laravel master and 5.0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel Framework and I wanted to know what is the difference between the Master and 5.0 (can be found at the documentation page).

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 5.0 branch is the **current stable release** all bugfixes and patches go to this branch and that's the one you should use. (it is also the one composer will use when you create a new project).

The master branch contains **the upcoming release**. In this case 5.1. However it could be unstable or suddenly break features because things will change in the new release.